# Systems architecture for small business ISP

Tags: web-services, design-patterns, architecture

I'm the only programmer of a pretty small ISP in a rural area with just around 2000 customers. Now I have finished a couple of semesters in university but I only have a couple of years of experience in the field so I'm uncertain of the architectural decisions that I'm making and was hoping somebody could help me pick the right path.

Most of our internal apps were created 8-10 years ago and are severely outdated and I have been given the job to replace those systems. Most of the basic underlying systems are solid but the apps that we use to manage our customers and connecting those to our internal systems are...lacking to say the least.

Most of these applications were created in PHP back in the day and are using mysql databases. I decided that i was going to create a couple of rest APIs using NodeJS on top of these databases and then create a central app that will take care of connecting all those systems together and making sure they stay up to date with one another.

Now for the question. I've been looking a bit into enterprise architecture and from what I've gathered going with this sort of micro service architecture seems to be a solid plan. However I've also seen a couple articles talking about message buses and my question is if i should instead set up a message bus, for example apache activemq so these services can talk together amongst themselves instead of using a central app that would handle managing all of them.

Are there any specific patterns that i should be reading up on or does what I've come up with look solid enough?

Comment: Hi, you should take a look at [http://martinfowler.com/books/eaa.html](http://martinfowler.com/books/eaa.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An enterprise service bus will add a lot of complexity to your design, so you need to look at the pro/con to see if it's really necessary. [Here is an article](http://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/mule-dev/to-esb-or-not-to-esb/) you can always upgrade your architecture in the future and migrate the services.

I run some complex services on Apache Tomcat and they work great. Supports a user pool of 70,000. If you build in connection pooling and redundancy you should be fine.